# Pre-load a web page using a browser extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, pageload, browser-extension

Currently, I have a Chrome browser extension that opens a specified web page in a new tab.

I would like the browser extension to completely pre-load the web page (including images and scripts) so it appears instantly when opened in a new tab.

Any idea on the best way to do this? If Chrome could load a web page in a hidden tab, I would do so and then have the hidden tab appear when the new tab button is clicked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Chrome extensions can have explicitly running background pages. Have you tried just loading it in there?

Comment: I haven't tried this-- I'm not sure how to utilize extension background pages to speed up the appearance of the page content itself. I'm hoping to have stuff like photos and iframes already loaded when the tab appears... how might the Chrome background page be used to preload and then display the HTML in entirety?

Comment: @Kevin, there aren't hidden tabs in Chrome.  There isn't an API or documented way to preload a webpage.  But you can try some reasonable methods (whose behavior can change without warning), like using the cache, loading the files from a background page like Jeff said, using XMLHttpRequest for example.  That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, you can try using a Chrome [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) to do what you want.  Set up the page with the content you want pre-loaded, and then you can open up and serve new content using whatever kind of request you'd like.  Read through the examples (or check out the source of your favorite extension) to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Thanks so much @Jeff and @YoArgentino! I appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: @Kevin Are there any news/progress/implementations?

Comment: @root The best approach likely depends on your use case: whether you control the web page, whether data needs to be fresh on load, and whether you can use a local extension page for the content. In our case, we ended up using a service worker to cache the web page that we want to load quickly.